# Escaping characters in attributes in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular to post to a webform. Using ng-model I need to build an array with values that have dots in them.

I would like something like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="quiz.entry.958924423" name="entry.958924423" required />
```

would correspond to an object like this:

```
$scope.quiz= {'entry.958924423': '1F9trPeu9DA4W0CjADN4a1fl3Jh682ZPF8remWB21RhI'};
```

now it makes

```
$scope.quiz.entry = 1F9trPeu9DA4W0CjADN4a1fl3Jh682ZPF8remWB21RhI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method, if I understand you correctly:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="quiz['entry.958924423']" required />
```